# Как вывести в Django admin поля из двух моделей?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-orm, django-model

Имеется 2 модели ClientComment и Client. Как я могу через (ClientAdmin) list_display вывести комментарии (последний) из ClientComment? Что-бы к каждому клиенту соответственно был выведен последний комментарий пользователя (допустим между столбцами номера телефона и датой рождений).

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import RandomCharField
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


from pytils import *




class ClientComment(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="comments")
    client_comment_body = models.TextField(verbose_name="Комментарий")
    client_comment_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Автор коментария", null=True,
                                            blank=True)
    client_comment_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Дата создания")
    client_comment_update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Обновлено")
    client_comment_slug = RandomCharField(length=15, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Комментарий"
        verbose_name_plural = "Комментарии"
        ordering = ['-client_comment_created_at']


    def __str__(self):
        return 'Коментарий создан {} в {}'.format(self.client_comment_user, self.client_comment_created_at)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("client", kwargs={"slug": self.client_comment_slug})


class Client(models.Model):
    NEW = "NW"
    INTERESTING = "IN"
    NOT_INTERESTING = "NI"
    NOT_ANSWER = "NO"
    FALSE_NUMBER = "FN"
    CALL_BACK = "CB"
    DEPOSIT = "DP"
    OFF_TELEPHONE = "OF"
    LAWYER = "LW"

    CLIENT_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (NEW, 'Новый'),
        (INTERESTING, 'Интересный'),
        (NOT_INTERESTING, 'Не инетесный'),
        (NOT_ANSWER, 'Не отвечает'),
        (FALSE_NUMBER, 'Не верный номер'),
        (CALL_BACK, 'Перезвонить'),
        (DEPOSIT, 'Депозит'),
        (OFF_TELEPHONE, 'Выключен'),
        (LAWYER, 'Аналитик'),
    ]


    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name="Фамилия")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name="Имя")
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, verbose_name="Отчество")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name="Электронная почта")
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, verbose_name="Номер телефона")
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Дата рождения")
    client_status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CLIENT_STATUS_CHOICES, default=NEW,
                                     verbose_name="Статус клиента")
    client_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Дата создания")
    client_update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Обновлено")
    is_processed = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Обработано")
    client_slug = RandomCharField(length=15, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Клиент"
        verbose_name_plural = "Клиенты"
        ordering = ["client_created_at"]


    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()



    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("client", kwargs={"slug": self.client_slug})
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from search_admin_autocomplete.admin import SearchAutoCompleteAdmin
from .models import Client, ClientComment

from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin
from import_export import resources



class ClientCommentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ClientComment
    fk_name = "client"


class ClientResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Client


class ClientAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ClientCommentInline,
    ]
    resource_class = ClientResource
    save_on_top = True
    list_display = ['id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'phone', 'client_created_at',
                    'client_status', "is_processed", ]
    radio_fields = {"client_status": admin.VERTICAL}
    list_display_links = list_display
    list_filter = ("client_status", "is_processed",)
    search_fields = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'phone',)
    list_per_page = 50
    list_max_show_all = 200
    readonly_fields = ('client_created_at', "client_slug", "client_update_at",)
    fields = (
        ('last_name', 'first_name', "middle_name"), ("email", 'phone'), "date_of_birth", ('client_created_at',
                                                                                          "client_update_at"),
        ('client_status', "is_processed"), "client_slug",
    )


admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```

Вот так выглядит админка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 вариант. у модели добавь метод `get_last_comment` который будет возвращать последний комментарий и в `list_display` укажи этот метод

```
def get_last_comment(self):
    last_comment = self.comments.first()
    return last_comment.client_comment_body if last_comment else '-'
get_last_comment.short_description = 'Последний комментарий' # это, что бы в админке колонка называлась адекватно
```

минусы этого варианта в том, что для каждой записи `Client` django будет обращаться к БД

2 вариант. сделать все тоже самое в `ModelAdmin`

```
def get_last_comment(self, client):
    return self.last_comments.get(obj.pk, '-)
get_last_comment.short_description = 'Последний комментарий'
```

но дополнительно нужно будет переопределить еще `get_paginator`, таким образом, что бы в нем одним запросом получить все последние комментарии по текущей выборке клиентов

```
def get_paginator(self, request, queryset, per_page, orphans=0, allow_empty_first_page=True):
    paginator = super().get_paginator(request, queryset, per_page, orphans=0, allow_empty_first_page=True)
    page_objects = paginator.page(int(request.GET.get('p'))+1)
    # создать запрос, который будет вытаскивать последний комментарий для всех записей , находящихся в `page_objects` и сохранить их в `self.last_comments`
    return paginator
```

Comment: Спасибо. Первый способ заработал из коробки, со вторым пока не совладал.